# Django Haystack - How can I display a date_facet in a template?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, faceted-search, facet

I'm using Solr with Haystack and I need to show a date facet in a Django Template, but I have no clue on how to use this result:

My sqs:

```
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().date_facet('date_inserted', start_date=datetime.date(2008,01,01), end_date=datetime.date(2012,01,01), gap_by='year')
>>> sqs.facet_counts()
```

The result is this:

```
{
'fields': {}, 
'dates': {
        'date_inserted': {
                                'end': '2012-01-01T00:00:00Z', 
                                    '2009-01-01T00:00:00Z': 0, 
                                    'gap': '+1YEAR/YEAR', 
                                    '2008-01-01T00:00:00Z': 0, 
                                    '2011-01-01T00:00:00Z': 637, 
                                    '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z': 0
                             }
     }, 
'queries': {}
}
```

How can I use this result in a Django Template? I need to facet by year, for example:

```
2011 (637)
2010 (0)
2009 (0)
2008 (0)
```

Any clue on how to achieve this on a Template?

Comment: did u find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/v1.2.2/faceting.html#display-the-facets-in-the-template

documentation gives great example